# Multiple TensorBoards with the same web-server

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

It's possible to run multiple tensorboard instances (with different log dirs) on the same machine. There is even the tensorboard.manager class that can start/re-use the TB processes.
The problem is that all those TBs run different web-servers on different ports.

I'd like to go one step further and have all those TBs under a same web-server with the single port. (And the TB's should be dynamic - so that new ones can be added on the fly.)

It would be great if I could just add '&logdir=gs://bla/bla' to the URL and have the TB corresponding to that log dir.

What's the easiest way to make this happen?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I did not investigate any more after the initial investigation.

Comment: @DarrenHall  I have posted an answer and it works fine on my linux machine.

Comment: @Ark-kun, I have posted an answer and it works fine on my linux machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--reuse_port=true` command with the `--path_prefix='/context/to/use'` to get your goal:

For example, if your logs are in the folders: `/path/to/folder1`, `/path/to/folder2` and `/path/to/folder3`, you can run:

```
tensorboard --logdir=/path/to/folder1 --bind_ip --port 8080 --reuse_port=true --path_prefix='/tensorboard/folder1'
tensorboard --logdir=/path/to/folder2 --bind_ip --port 8080 --reuse_port=true --path_prefix='/tensorboard/folder2'
tensorboard --logdir=/path/to/folder3 --bind_ip --port 8080 --reuse_port=true --path_prefix='/tensorboard/folder3'
```

This has worked fine for me on `amazon-linux-2` with tensorboard greater than `2.1.0`

Comment: For some reason, `--reuse_port=true` doesn't seem to work anymore. I still get the error `TensorBoard could not bind to port XXXX, it was already in use`

Comment: @Phoenix I think your best alternative is to use a `nginx` server for reverse proxy. If you running this on any kubernetes system I found a way to run multiple boards on different ports and expose them in different paths, just need to use different `service` associated with the ports of your `pod`

Answer (score 0):

`--reuse_port=true` flag didn't work in my case. So, here is a pure Python based solution that implements a redirect server that sends HTTP 302 redirects to the client with the appropriate tensorboard instance running on a given port. This is achieved by having an internal mapping between ports and tensorboard path prefixes.

In this case, the client only needs to connect to a fixed port with the appropriate path prefix referring to a given tensorboard instance. This solution uses standard Python 3 libraries only.

The following script starts a number of tensorboard instances as well as the redirection server.

```py
import subprocess
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
from socketserver import TCPServer

PORT_MAP = {}
CLIENT_CONNECTS_TO_THIS_PORT = xxxx
IP = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
PATHS = ['/path/first', '/path/second', '/path/third']


class RedirectServer(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        """handles get request for example"""
        print('received request for', self.path)

        try:
            proc_port = PORT_MAP[self.path]
        except KeyError:
            self.send_response(404)
            return

        # mapping exists for this path, send redirect
        self.send_response(302)
        new_path = f'http://{IP}:{proc_port}{self.path}'
        self.send_header('Location', new_path)
        self.end_headers()


def main():
    global PORT_MAP
    i = 1
    procs = []

    try:
        #  start tensorboard instances on the following ports per path
        for path in PATHS:
            proc_port = CLIENT_CONNECTS_TO_THIS_PORT + i

            #  note that path prefix must be given and it should listen on appropriate interfaces
            procs.append(subprocess.Popen(f'tensorboard --logdir data/{path}/log_dir --host 0.0.0.0 '
                                              f'--port {proc_port} --path_prefix={path} '
                                              f'--window_title {path}'.split(),
                                              shell=False))

            #  record the mapping between instance port and path prefix
            PORT_MAP[path] = proc_port
            i += 1

        #  start the redirect server
        server = TCPServer(('', CLIENT_CONNECTS_TO_THIS_PORT), RedirectServer)
        server.serve_forever()
    finally:
        # kill tensorboard instances
        for proc in procs:
            proc.kill()

        # close server
        if 'server' in locals():
            server.server_close()
```